# Backup Directorios desde pagina PHP

Tags: php, script

necesito hacer un backup del directorio /var/www/html que es el que contiene mi pagina web.

La idea es que al clicar el botón lleve a ese script, el cual realiza el backup y lo DESCARGA

He probado con este script en PHP:

```
<?php


# Name of the buckup file
$filename = 'BACKUP_' . date('Y.m.d') . '.tar.gz';
# Target path where to save the file
$targetPath = '/var/www/html/';
# Directory to backup
$dir = "/var/www/";  
# Execute the tar command and save file
system( "tar -pczf ".$targetPath ."".$filename." ".$dir );

readfile("{$targetPath}{$filename}"); // outputs file contents to a browser
unlink("{$targetPath}{$filename}"); // removes file from disk

?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo buscar cada una de las funciones que pusiste en el código que obviamente sacaste de Internet y no sabes para que sirve https://www.php.net/

Comment: Qué error tienes?

Comment: Me muestra el mismo contenido, como texto plano en la página